# Search by index with doctrine

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I don't know much about indexes in database, so my question can be stupid but...
I have parameters for person (name, surname, organization, job etc.), now I'm creating index string in `prePersist()` method, something like this:

```
$this->search_index = $this->name.' '.$this->surname.' '.$this->orgnaization;
```

with further searching by exploded string with " ", and comparing each part using `LIKE`  with search_index.

But this looks very crazy. What is the best practice?
p.s. my sample code:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
foreach(explode(" ", $query) as $key=>$part){
     $queryBuilder->orWhere('s.searchindex LIKE:name'.$key)
          ->setParameter('name'.$key, $part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, I guess then you are looking for something like this:

```
$collection = Doctrine::getTable('User')->createQuery('u');
    ->where('column_name LIKE ?', $this->name)
    ->orWhere('column_surname LIKE ?', $this->surname)
    ->orWhere('column_organization LIKE ?', $this->organization)
    ->execute();
```

Comment: So the problem, that user can enter something like this: "John Engineer Stevenson"